# How to get highest three values of a group without pandas or itertools?

Tags: python

I have data like so:

```
groupid    value        id
A             1         annie
A             2         sally
A             3         tom
A             4         paul
A             5         frank
B             6         annie
B             7         sally
B             8         susan
B             9         poe
B             10        teddy
.             .          .
.             .          .
.             .          .
```

The data is constructed so there is a grouping id, `groupid`, an individual within the group, `id`, and a value for each individual in the group, `value`.

I would like to collect the `id` entries for the highest three values in each group.

So, for `groupid` `A`, I would like the following list: `[frank, paul, tom]` and for `groupid` `B`, I would like this list: `[teddy, poe, susan]`

I understand this is possible with tools such as `groupby` in `pandas` or `itertools`, but how can I do this efficiently without use of packages/imported modules?

Here is how I would calculate the (singular) highest value:

```
groups = [A, B]

max = 0

for group in groups:
    for line in data:
        if groupid == group:
           if value > max:
              max = value
              max_id = id
```

However, this approach gets clunky when it becomes necessary to collect more than just the maximum value (I want the highest three values).

The data is a list of lists, such as:

```
[['A', 1, 'annie'], ['A', 2, 'ally'], ['A', 3, 'tom'], ...]
```

I continued the example I used to get the maximum value, but defined several variables `highest_value`, `second_highest`, `third_highest`, adding relevant conditions to fill these variables correctly. Although it works, it gets clunky.

Comment: You want to do this with no imports at all... not even the Python standard library which has all the components needed to do this effectively?

Comment: unfortunately, I am limited from using these advanced packages :(

Comment: The data in your example is sorted. Is this the case with the real data? If not, have you considered just sorting it, which would make the problem much easier at a (maybe) small performance expense?

Comment: It sure sounds like you're asking us to do your homework. . . .  Otherwise, you'd be using `heapq.nlargest` and be done with it.

Comment: First do it with the imports, then just copy the implementation they use in the libraries - voila! You'd be learning along the way too!

Comment: Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Even if this isn't homework per se, some of the advice still applies, like "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first".

Comment: To be clear, you're not allowed to use *any* imports, right? Otherwise you could use `heapq.nlargest` like Frank said.

Comment: What format is the input in? Is it a text file? A Pandas dataframe? If it's a dataframe, how are you supposed to read it in without using imports?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, ah yes my apologies good question. The data is a list of lists, I will update the post to specify this

Comment: What are A and B? Are they variables? Strings? This isn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: They are strings, sorry about that. Post is updated

Comment: Why not sort the items of each group and take the first 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several comments have stated, you can use sorting and then take the largest three elements:

```py
data = ...

groups = {}

# Separate into groups.
for group_id, value, name in data:
    if group_id not in groups:
        groups[group_id] = []
    groups[group_id].append((value, name))

# Sort each group.
for data_points in groups.values():
    data_points.sort(key=lambda x: -x[0])

# Extract top three data points.
result = {}
for group_id in groups:
    result[group_id] = [groups[group_id][i][1] for i in range(min(len(groups[group_id]), 3))]
print(result)
```

If you have a large number of data points, you may be able to make this faster by using quick-select or by writing your own heap implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

@BrokenBenchmark has more concise code, but this works, too:

```
# starts with some arbitrary lists of which to assess the order
groups = sum(([x]*y for x,y in zip(['A', 'B', 'C'], (3, 3, 3))),[])
value = [i for i in range(1, 10)]
id = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('i') + 1)]

# find the unique groups
def unique(entries):
    unique_list = []

    for x in entries:
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
    return unique_list

# find which indices are relevant for each group
def find(entries, a):  # a is a single index from unique list
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(entries) if x == a]

# find the values in the list that fall at specific indices
def which(found, what): # found is the list of indices, what is the list to parse
    return [what[i] for i in found]

def swapper(entries, pos1, pos2):
    entries[pos1], entries[pos2] = entries[pos2], entries[pos1]
    return entries

def leaders(amt, who):  # values and names, but only the indices per group
    k = amt.copy()
    m = who.copy()
    for i in range(len(amt)):
        maxI = i
        maxA = amt[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(amt)):
            if amt[j] > maxA:
                maxI = j
                maxA = amt[j]
            k = swapper(k, i, maxI)
            m = swapper(m, i, maxI)
    return k, m

# find the unique groups
# for each group
#   look for the indices that represent that group
#   look for the values in the other arrays that match these indices
#   find the top three
uGr = unique(groups)
print("Unique Groups")
print(uGr)

# this runs through the methods for each group
for i in uGr:
    finallyD = []
    forRealD = []
    print("Working with group: ", i)
    g_ins = find(groups, i)
    where = which(g_ins, value)
    where2 = which(g_ins, id)
    finallyD, forRealD = leaders(where, where2)

    print("For group", i," the top three are:\n", list(zip(finallyD[0:3], forRealD[0:3])))
```

The output lets you know the following:

```
Unique Groups
['A', 'B', 'C']
Working with group:  A
For group A  the top three are:
 [(3, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'a')]
Working with group:  B
For group B  the top three are:
 [(6, 'f'), (5, 'e'), (4, 'd')]
Working with group:  C
For group C  the top three are:
 [(9, 'i'), (8, 'h'), (7, 'g')]
[Finished in 0.05s]
```